# How to send custom sound push notification with OneSignal?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, onesignal

I am wondering how to send custom sound notification with `OneSignal`. Unfortunately their docs only cover the sending through the dashboard: [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-sounds)

My approach which didn't work:

```
OneSignal.defaultClient().postNotification([
"contents": ["en": "test"],
"include_player_ids": [pushId],
"aps": ["sound": "sound.wav"],
])
```

This also didn't work:

```
OneSignal.defaultClient().postNotification([
"contents": ["en": "test"],
"include_player_ids": [pushId],
"sound": "sound.wav",
])
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, seems like `"ios_sound": "sound.wav"` does the job:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#page-create-notification